# SysTick interrupt causes execution to jump to 0x1fffxxxx on STM32F030

Tags: arm, stm32, interrupt-handling

I'm trying to use `SysTick_Handler` in SW4STM32 for Linux, but whenever the SysTick interrupt is triggered, execution jumps to somewhere in system memory. By my understanding, it should jump into the `void SysTick_Handler(void)` that I declared, or failing that, into `Default_Handler` declared in startup_stm32.s where the interrupt vector table is defined. I set a break point in my `SysTick_Handler`, but it is never reached. In the code below, it gets through `init_systick()` and stays in the endless `for` loop if I don't include `SysTick_CTRL_TICKINT_Msk`, as expected, but when I do include it, the debugger tells me it ends up somewhere around address 0x1fffda7c.

main.c:

```
#include "stm32f0xx.h"

volatile uint32_t ticks = 0;

void SysTick_Handler(void) {
    ticks++;
}

void init_systick(void) {
    SysTick->LOAD = 43999;
    SCB->SHP[1] |= 0x40000000L;
    SysTick->VAL = 0;
    SysTick->CTRL = SysTick_CTRL_CLKSOURCE_Msk | SysTick_CTRL_TICKINT_Msk | SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;
}

int main(void)
{
    init_systick();
    for(;;);
}
```

I verified from the `.map` file that the linker is using the declared `SysTick_Handler` instead of `Default_Handler`.

I also tried the following variation to use the standard peripheral library for setup, along with other interrupt priority values, with the same results:

```
#include "stm32f0xx.h"

volatile uint32_t ticks = 0;

void SysTick_Handler(void) {
    ticks++;
}

void init_systick(void) {
    SysTick_Config(44000);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(SysTick_IRQn);
    NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    init_systick();
    for(;;);
}
```

This shouldn't be relevant, but since the target doesn't have a timing crystal, I also modified `void SetSysClock(void)` in system_stm32f0xx.c to use the HSI clock and PLL, which appears to be working correctly:

```
static void SetSysClock(void)
{
    RCC->CFGR = (RCC->CFGR & ~RCC_CFGR_SW) | RCC_CFGR_SW_HSI;
    while ((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_HSI) ;
    FLASH->ACR = FLASH_ACR_PRFTBE | FLASH_ACR_LATENCY;
    RCC->CR &= ~RCC_CR_PLLON;
    while (RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY) ;
    RCC->CFGR = (RCC->CFGR & ~RCC_CFGR_PLLMUL & ~RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC) | RCC_CFGR_PLLMUL11;   // PLL takes 8 MHz HSI / 2 as input
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;
    while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY)) ;
    RCC->CFGR = (RCC->CFGR & ~RCC_CFGR_SW) | RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;
    while ((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL) ;
}
```

**-- EDIT: More info requested in the comments --**

It's an M0 core, so it doesn't have vector table relocation. From the reference manual section 2.5 (page 44):

> Unlike Cortex ® M3 and M4, the M0 CPU does not support the vector table relocation.

Address 0x00000000 should be mapped either to FLASH memory at 0x08000000, system memory at 0x1fffd800, or to SRAM at 0x20000000. The memory at address 0x00000000 matches system memory at 0x1fffd800, even though SYSCFG_CFGR1 MEM_MODE is set to 00, which should map FLASH memory there. Main FLASH memory at address 0x08000000 contains the correct vector table, but address 0x00000000 is populated with address 0x1fffd99d for the SysTick vector (and all other non-NULL vectors except the reset vector, which is 0x1fffdc41); the vectors shown by the debugger at address 0x00000000 are consistent with the observed behavior. All of this information was collected while paused at a breakpoint at address 0x08000298 (a correct position in FLASH memory where the correct code has been loaded), before executing the interrupt.

Comment: Check not the map file, but the actual position in the vtor table

Comment: Where can I find the vector table? I'm used to it being in the disassembly listing, but if SW4STM32 generates it, I can't find it.

Comment: I dumped the .bin file and the vector at 0x0000003c (which should be for SysTick) contains the address that the .map file assigned to my SysTick_Handler from main.o

Comment: Use the debugger. Break and see the actual value of the vector (using VTOR value)

Comment: please post the disassembly of the vector table and the handler(s) in question.

Comment: Updated original post...it's definitely using the wrong vector table, but I don't know why and there is no VTOR register

Comment: Idk why StackOverflow is being so lame, but I posted the final fix based on the behavior I observed, which has been buried below, event though, as the OP, I can attest that the answers above it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said already, in Cortex-M0 there's no VTOR register and the vector table is at the fixed address of 0x0000'0000. However, in STM32 based on Cortex-M0 (which is only in STM32F0xx), one of three memories (User FLASH, System ROM, RAM) can be mapped onto this address, depending on SYSCFG_CFGR1.MEM_MODE bitfield.

Content of this bitfield depends on the boot process during reset (see below), and can be observed and changed in program, but only if SYSCFG's clock is enabled in RCC (by setting the somewhat confusingly named RCC_APB2ENR.SYSCFGCOMPEN bit - failing to do this is a common pitfall, resulting in SYSCFG registers reading as zero; and that's probably why OP thought SYSCFG_CFGR1.MEM_MODE is zero even if the System ROM was mapped to 0x0000'0000, thus SYSCFG_CFGR1.MEM_MODE was in fact set to 0b01).

In most STM32F0xx, content of SYSCFG_CFGR1.MEM_MODE after reset is determined by combination of BOOT0 pin and BOOT_SEL/nBOOTx bits in option bytes. However, [in some particular models](http://efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g44.html), there is an additional mechanism, where upon power-on reset the first address in User FLASH is checked against 0xFFFF'FFFF and if this is the case, the System ROM is mapped at 0x0000'0000. This in effect runs the built-in bootloader, when such chip is run the first time, with empty FLASH.

This "empty check" is performed only upon power-on reset (or using the lesser-known OBL_LAUNCH mechanism), and is retained through non-power-on resets, resulting in System ROM being mapped at 0x0000'0000 upon all subsequent resets until power-on reset, even if the User FLASH has been reprogrammed.

Some debugging tools may "know" about this feature and may use OBL_LAUNCH to hide this problem from the user. Others may not.

One of the STM32 models which do have this "empty check" mechanism is STM32F030xC (OP never told us which particular STM32F030 is he using, and there are 3 distinct models of it). See *Empty check* section of Boot configuration chapter in RM0360.

Answer (score 3):

The VTOR is referenced in the arm-v6 reference manual. It is a good idea to check this. 
https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0419/d/DDI0419D_armv6m_arm.pdf

> 0xE000ED08 VTOR RW 0x00000000a Vector Table Offset Register, VTOR on page B3-231

That reference manual is for the arm-v6M architecture which is the architecture for cortex-m0 processors. This is the bible. Most of the generic cortex-m0 features of the stm line will not be mentioned in stm refrenece manuals, just in the arm arm.

I'll reiterate, check the VTOR.

And make sure you are building for the right line of STM32F030!

The STM32F030x4 and STM32F030x6 micros have a different memory map than the STM32F030x8.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like there might be a problem with the linker file.

Can you verify that your linker file has something that looks like the following? (if it is a default file it will probably be far more complex).

```
. = 0;
.text 0 :
{
    *(.vector);
    crt0*(.text*);
main*(.text*);
    *(.text*);
} > flash
```

Basically what this is saying is that the 'text' (code) of the program starts at address 0x0, and the first thing to put there is the vector table, followed by startup code, main, and then other code.

You will also then want to check that you have some file specifying this vector table's contents that also agrees it should be at address 0x0. This example is from an ATSAMD21E18A.

```
.section .vector, "a", %progbits

.equ stack_base, 0x20004000

.word stack_base
.word reset_handler
.word nmi_handler
.word hardfault_handler
.word 0
// ...
.word 0
.word systick_handler
// ...
```

The important thing is that it is marked as the section `vector` which the linker file will try to put at 0x0. For a processor with VTOR (like the M0+), this table might be specified in C without any special markings, and its location won't matter, but since you don't have VTOR, you need to make sure the linker knows to put this section right at 0x0.

Answer (score 0):

jonnconn is correct. VTOR is the issue. I just wanted to add to his post (but cannot because my reputation isn't high enough) that I ran into this issue recently with a new CubeMx project.

VTOR is set to 0 on reset. VTOR is initialized in low level init before main. SystemInit in system_stm32l4xx.c (or similar for your part) seems to only initialize VTOR if USER_VECT_TAB_ADDRESS is defined. But CubeMx had this commented out. I had to uncomment it (it is in the same file), and leave VECT_TAB_OFFSET as 0. Afterwards, VTOR config was correctly set to FLASH_BASE (assuming VECT_TAB_SRAM was left undefined).

Answer (score -1):

According the [datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJrMmsi4LcAhVlxFkKHallB8AQFggwMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fdatasheet%2Fstm32f030rc.pdf&usg=AOvVaw01oxVNMYrsWOia2sxtEoA1), that region is the system memory (for built-in bootloader). You may try two things:

1. Double check BOOTx pins to make sure the MCU loads FLASH instead of the system memory.
2. Make sure you assigned [`SCB->VTOR`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0662a/Ciheijba.html) to the correct address of your own interrupt vector table.

Comment: 1. BOOT0 is connected to GND, which causes it to boot into main FLASH. Also, I verified by stepping in the debugger that it starts in the code I've loaded into FLASH.

2. I saw VTOR mentioned in a post on an LPC microcontroller, but it doesn't seem to be defined in the CMSIS headers created by the IDE, and I can't find any reference to it in the datasheet, reference manual, or programming manual for the STM32F030 series.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the STM Cortex M0 chips do this weird thing where everything is correct, but the interrupt vector table doesn't update until you power cycle the chip. The programmer's reset doesn't do it. Has to be a hard power cycle. Can't find this documented anywhere, but it's the behavior I have observed. Program a new chip, doesn't work, power cycle it, it works. Try another new chip, doesn't work, power cycle it, then it works. *SMH*

Comment: No - it is completely wrong what you wrote.

Comment: @gulpr This is the behavior I observed repeatedly on several units. Using STM's programmer, the firmware I was uploading would hang after programming, even if reset again, until I power cycled it, then it would work fine. If you can suggest a better explanation, please do so.

Comment: Your observation does not lead to the correct conclusions.

Comment: @gulpr I was posting observations, not conclusions. week found the correct answer above, which I have marked as correct. Basically, STM32F0xx does a check for empty flash and locks itself into the built-in bootloader but it only does this check for power-on reset or if you use a special mechanism that I, and apparently STM's programmer/IDE, didn't know about. Hence, interrupts do not function correctly after programming for the first time until you power cycle or use the special reset mechanism. This explains all of the observations I have posted on this subject.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).